# Adding URL shortcut to mobile screen through a link on the website

Tags: android, iphone, asp.net, html

Do you know if it's possible to add URL shortcut to mobile screen through a link on the website?

So the workflow will goes like :

1. user clicks on a link on the website
2. pop up box appears, ask user to name the short cut link
3. user click on create and a shortcut been added to the mobile device's home screen with default icon.

I am interested in knowing whether this is possible for iphone and android devices. I've been searching for a while, but wasn't able to find any info on this...

Comment: Did you try this? n may be it meets your requirement https://github.com/okamototk/jqm-mobile-bookmark-bubble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible. You are only able to specify you icon to be added to the home screen, but not adding the shortcut directly by javascript.

Answer (score 0):

in iphone  you can do this [in this way](http://browsers.about.com/od/howtousemobilebrowser1/ss/iphonehomeicons.htm)

in android you may do like [in this way](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cb7aCMspNUg)

Comment: that's not what I am after. The link you provided requires user to manually add the shortcut by interacting with the browser. What I want is a link within the web page that will do all the work for you. Imagine you visit ur favour site, would it be cool if the site has a button on the page says "Add me to your home screen"?